# Given $f(x)=x^n+px + q, \ n\in{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

**Problem:** Given $f(x)=x^n+px+q, \ n\in{\mathbb{N}}, \ x\in\mathbb{R},$ determine (as a function of $n$) the maximum number of distinctive real roots that $f$ can have for $p,q\in\mathbb{R}.$

I need help to understand this problem. Below follows a solution from my professor, but I don't really understand.

**Solution:**

$n=1:$ One real root for $p\neq-1$ and no real root if $p=-1$.

$n\geq2:$ In this case, $f'(x)$ must have a root between the two roots for $f(x)$. The derivative $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+p$ has one root for even $n$ and max two roots for odd $n\Rightarrow f$ has max two roots for even $n$ and max three for odd $n$.

---

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? I understand the first $n=1$ case but for the second case I have the following questions:

1. If $n=2$, then I understand why $f'(x)$ must have one root between the two roots of $f(x)$. This is because in order for $f(x)$ to have two roots, the derivative must change sign so that the function changes direction and intercepts the $x$-axis again. But she never specifies if it's for $n>2$ or $n=2.$
2. Why is this statement true: "the derivative has one root for even $n$ and max two roots for odd $n$"?

Any help to understand this is welcome. If there are simpler methods to prove this, only using differentiation, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if I add in some words to the case $n \ge 2$ then it will become clearer.
*If* $f$ has at least two real roots *then* the derivative has a root in between. This is true regardless of $n$.

Now, note that $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+p$, so that $f'(x)=0 \iff x^{n-1}=-p/n$. So how many roots can $f'$ have? Well, if $n-1$ is odd then the function $x \to x^{n-1}$ is a bijection, so this equation always has a unique solution. In that case $f'(x)$ has exactly one root, so $f$ may have at most two roots (it could in principle have 0,1, or 2).

Similarly if $n-1$ is even, then $x^{n-1}$ is always positive: it could be possible that $x^{n-1}=-p/n$ has 0,1 or 2 solutions. In any case, it has at most 2 roots. Then $f$ must have at most 3 roots, since if it had 4 then we could find 3 roots of the derivative by looking in between the 3 consecutive pairs of roots.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you!

Comment: Question: So if $n-1$ is even, is the function $x\rightarrow x^{n-1}$ surjective?

Comment: No - if $n-1$ is even then $x^{n-1}$ cannot be negative! Think of the case of $x \to x^{2}$. & you're welcome :)

Comment: So is it injective? surjective? bijective?

Comment: It is none of those - I really urge you to think about this with $n$ as an actual number. Is $x \to x^{2}$ injective? surjective?

Comment: I already have done that, I even drew the function for a few odd and even $n'$s. I just thought that a function always had a name, maybe something I've not heard of yet. But I understand now, thanks again buddy.